# WebRTC Error: "STUN binding request timed out."

Tags: typescript, webrtc, real-time, sveltekit, peerjs

I am creating a small video-calling app using Svelte and the [PeerJS library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/peerjs). The code I wrote does not work for some reason and I cannot find why. I have searched Stack Overflow, referenced the documentation for help and talked to a couple friends, but nobody seems to know what's wrong in my code.

The function in the TypeScript file `init(id: any, host: any, hostAudio: any, reciever: any, recieverAudio: any)` is called in the frontend with a unique ID, a video element called "host" an audio element called "hostAudio", another video element called "reciever" and another audio element called "recieverAudio". It is then supposed to setup the Peerjs event listeners `call` and `open` (see ["Video/audio calls" section](https://peerjs.com/docs/) in the PeerJS documentation).

There is a call button in the frontend that when pressed invokes the `call( person: any, host: any, hostAudio: any, reciever: any, recieverAudio: any )` function that carries the same parameters as the `init(id: any, host: any, hostAudio: any, reciever: any, recieverAudio: any)` function with the only difference of the first parameter (`id: any`) being the ID of the other person.

This code used to work, but now it doesn't. When connecting it now throws an error - namely `"ERROR PeerJS:  Error: Could not connect to peer 1673299757"`.

Here is the code for the Svelte frontend component that initiates a call written in Svelte's TypeScript mode

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import Fa from 'svelte-fa';
    import { faHome, faPhone } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    import voicecall, { init } from '$lib/xs/Ether/voicecall';
    import { getUser } from '$lib/xs/Ether/User/UID';
    export let icon = faHome;

    // Voicecall Hooks
    export let call = false;
    let callPane: HTMLDivElement;
    let hostVideo: HTMLVideoElement;
    let recieverVideo: HTMLVideoElement;
    let hostAudio: HTMLAudioElement;
    let recieverAudio: HTMLAudioElement;
    let person = $page.url.searchParams.get('with') || { ID: '' };

    // Read storage
    import 'node-localstorage/register';
    const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')) || {};
    if (call) {
        getUser(person)
            .then(function (json) {
                person = json;
                person = person;
                console.log(person);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('The user could not be found', error);
            });
    }
    onMount(() => {
        if (call) {
            // Create a new connection
            init(hostVideo, hostAudio, recieverVideo, recieverAudio);
        }
    });
</script>

<div
    class="top-navigation z-50 m-0 flex h-16 w-full flex-row flex-wrap items-center bg-opacity-60 text-text shadow-lg"
>
    <div class="titlebar flex w-full justify-around px-4">
        <div class="pageTitle flex items-center justify-center">
            <Fa {icon} size="18" />
            <h5 class="title-text">
                <slot name="title-text">Home</slot>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer flex-1">&nbsp;</div>
        {#if call}
            <div class="phonecall flex items-center justify-center px-4">
                <button
                    on:click={() => {
                        voicecall(person.ID, hostVideo, hostAudio, recieverVideo, recieverAudio);
                        callPane.classList.remove('hidden');
                    }}
                    class="rounded bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-20 px-4 py-2 hover:bg-opacity-40"
                    ><Fa icon={faPhone} size="18" /></button
                >
            </div>
        {/if}
        <div class="logout">
            <button
                class="rounded bg-red-800 px-4 py-2 font-semibold text-white hover:opacity-80"
                on:click={() => {
                    localStorage.clear();
                    window.location.reload();
                }}
            >
                Logout</button
            >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div
        id="callPane"
        class="callPane hidden h-full w-full basis-full bg-text bg-opacity-100"
        bind:this={callPane}
    >
        <div
            class="callContainer flex flex-wrap items-center justify-around bg-text bg-opacity-90 py-4"
        >
            <div
                class="mx-4 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden rounded bg-primary"
                style="width: 500px; height: 400px"
            >
                <video
                    bind:this={hostVideo}
                    width="500px"
                    muted={true}
                    on:loadedmetadata={() => {
                        hostVideo = hostVideo;
                    }}
                    class="hidden"
                />
                {#if hostVideo}
                    {#if hostVideo.classList.contains('hidden')}
                        <img
                            class="rounded-full border-8 border-tertiary px-2 py-2"
                            width="150px"
                            src={userData.avatar}
                            alt={userData.username + "'s Avatar"}
                        />
                    {/if}
                {/if}
                <audio bind:this={hostAudio} src="" muted={true} class="hidden" />
            </div>
            <div
                class="mx-4 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden rounded bg-primary"
                style="width: 500px; height: 400px"
            >
                <video
                    bind:this={recieverVideo}
                    width="500px"
                    on:loadedmetadata={() => {
                        recieverVideo = recieverVideo;
                    }}
                    class="hidden"
                />
                {#if recieverVideo}
                    {#if recieverVideo.classList.contains('hidden')}
                        <img
                            class="rounded-full border-8 border-tertiary px-2 py-2"
                            width="150px"
                            src={person.avatar}
                            alt={person.username + "'s Avatar"}
                        />
                    {/if}
                {/if}

                <audio bind:this={recieverAudio} src="" class="hidden" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the code for the Voicecall functions used in that frontend code

```js
import { Peer } from 'peerjs';
import { http_host, API_BASE } from '$lib/xs/config.json';
const UID = localStorage.getItem('UID');
let peer: any;

export function init(host: any, hostAudio: any, reciever: any, recieverAudio: any) {
    const id = UID;
    console.log('P2P initialized with ID #' + id);
    // Get the peer and give the script access to the callPane
    peer = new Peer(id, {
        debug: 3,
        config: {
            iceServers: [
                { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
                { urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
                { urls: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302' },
                { urls: 'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302' },
                { urls: 'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302' },
                { urls: 'turn:0.peerjs.com:3478', username: 'peerjs', credential: 'peerjsp' }
            ],
            sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan',
            iceTransportPolicy: 'relay'
        }
    });
    peer.on('open', (id: any) => {
        console.log('Opened P2P connection.');
    });
    peer.on('call', (call: any) => {
        const acceptCall = confirm('You are being called. Do you want to receive it?');
        if (acceptCall) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then((stream) => {
                call.answer(stream); //  @ts-ignore We reference the callPane by ID
                addStream(host, stream, hostAudio);
                callPane.classList.remove('hidden');
                call.on('stream', (stream: MediaStream) => addStream(reciever, stream, recieverAudio));
                call.on('close', () => reciever.remove());
            });
        }
    });
}

export default function call(
    person: any,
    host: any,
    hostAudio: any,
    reciever: any,
    recieverAudio: any
) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then((stream) => {
        addStream(host, stream, hostAudio);
        callUser(person, stream, host, reciever, recieverAudio);
    });
}

function addStream(video: any, stream: any, audio: any) {
    console.log(stream);
    if (stream.getVideoTracks().length > 0) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => video.play());
        video.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
    if (stream.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
        // Do something with the audio
        audio.srcObject = stream;
        audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => audio.play());
        audio.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
}

// Returns who all is online on the server
function onLineUsers() {
    return fetch(`${http_host}${API_BASE}users/online`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            return response;
        })
        .catch((error) => console.warn(error));
}

async function callUser(user: any, stream: any, host: any, reciever: any, recieverAudio: any) {
    const users = await onLineUsers().then((users) => {
        return users;
    });
    // If the user is online, we try to call them
    if (users[user]) {
        const call = peer.call(user, stream);
        console.log(`Calling ${user}...`);
        call.on('stream', (stream: MediaStream) => addStream(reciever, stream, recieverAudio));
        call.on('close', () => reciever.remove());
    } else {
        alert('The user is offline. Cannot call.');
    }
}
```

- I tried using a local Peerjs server. That did not work.
- I tried comparing my code to another person's code that worked. That did not seem to help since their working code looks the same to mine
- I tried using a totally different computer on a totally different network. That didn't help at all
- I verified that my IDs aren't being used by someone else since I'm using a public Peerjs server. There's no way on earth that my userIDs are in use since the `person.ID` and `UID` variables are retrieved on a database where they have already been randomly generated.
- I made sure that my `localStorage` calls are being loaded properly and not throwing an `undefined` variable into the `Peer()` constructor.
- I checked to make sure that my TURN/STUN servers are properly functional and that the peerJS public server was up before trying again
- As mentioned before the IDs are not in use
- The `call` event seems to work properly and the `addStream` function does not seem to have trouble adding streams when invoked directly.

I tried everything I could. The Svelte component is just another component on my page. The weird thing is that it worked before but I forgot to save my work. After working on it some more it just stopped working. Ever since I cannot get it to start working again.

## Environment

The environment I used is Windows 11 Pro and I used the default SvelteKit project generated by running `npm create svelte@latest my-app`. The code did not work on this locally hosted environment. As stated by [@sungryeol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9292770/sungryeol) I thought this was a hardware issue but unfortunately it does not seem too much like it. I uploaded this code to a Fly.io instance and it still failed to work. I tried this on multiple different devices and checking the JavaScript console reveals the error.

This possibly rules out both the environment and hardware as being issues.

**[EDIT]**
Checking the WebRTC Internals logs revealed the following

#### STUN Server Error

```
icecandidateerror

url: stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302
address: 172.19.64.x
port: 64098
host_candidate: 172.19.64.x:64098
error_text: STUN binding request timed out.
error_code: 701
```

#### TURN Server Error

```
url: turn:0.peerjs.com:3478?transport=udp
address: 192.168.56.x
port: 60506
host_candidate: 192.168.56.x:60506
error_text: TURN allocate request timed out.
error_code: 701
```

**[EDIT #2]** I have tried using a different turn server and turning off the relay policy but it still fails to work

**[EDIT #3]** Here is the entire console error list

```
Calling 1673750880...
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Created offer.
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Set localDescription: RTCSessionDescription {type: 'offer', sdp: 'v=0\r\no=- 557477221463746724 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=…c37b7bdd5e fb766db6-f3ff-4263-80e5-b147b5c96d57\r\n'} for:1673750880
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:466559609 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.200.1…893 typ host generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 1', sdpMid: '0', sdpMLineIndex: 0, foundation: '466559609', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:3223424676 1 udp 2122194687 172.19.64.1 …894 typ host generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 2', sdpMid: '0', sdpMLineIndex: 0, foundation: '3223424676', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:3530058244 1 udp 2122129151 192.168.56.1…895 typ host generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 3', sdpMid: '0', sdpMLineIndex: 0, foundation: '3530058244', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:466559609 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.200.1…896 typ host generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 1', sdpMid: '1', sdpMLineIndex: 1, foundation: '466559609', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:3223424676 1 udp 2122194687 172.19.64.1 …897 typ host generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 2', sdpMid: '1', sdpMLineIndex: 1, foundation: '3223424676', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:3530058244 1 udp 2122129151 192.168.56.1…898 typ host generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 3', sdpMid: '1', sdpMLineIndex: 1, foundation: '3530058244', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:1713025101 1 udp 1686052607 190.197.56.6… rport 63893 generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 1', sdpMid: '0', sdpMLineIndex: 0, foundation: '1713025101', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:1713025101 1 udp 1686052607 190.197.56.6… rport 63896 generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 1', sdpMid: '1', sdpMLineIndex: 1, foundation: '1713025101', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:1694548193 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.200.…ptype active generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 1', sdpMid: '0', sdpMLineIndex: 0, foundation: '1694548193', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:3203296316 1 tcp 1518214911 172.19.64.1 …ptype active generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 2', sdpMid: '0', sdpMLineIndex: 0, foundation: '3203296316', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:2896660636 1 tcp 1518149375 192.168.56.1…ptype active generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 3', sdpMid: '0', sdpMLineIndex: 0, foundation: '2896660636', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:1694548193 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.200.…ptype active generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 1', sdpMid: '1', sdpMLineIndex: 1, foundation: '1694548193', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:3203296316 1 tcp 1518214911 172.19.64.1 …ptype active generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 2', sdpMid: '1', sdpMLineIndex: 1, foundation: '3203296316', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:2896660636 1 tcp 1518149375 192.168.56.1…ptype active generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 3', sdpMid: '1', sdpMLineIndex: 1, foundation: '2896660636', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:2095376827 1 udp 41885695 5.78.45.120 65… rport 63896 generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 1', sdpMid: '1', sdpMLineIndex: 1, foundation: '2095376827', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Received ICE candidates for 1673750880: RTCIceCandidate {candidate: 'candidate:4230759973 1 udp 41885695 130.61.225.54 … rport 63893 generation 0 ufrag Gsrv network-id 1', sdpMid: '0', sdpMLineIndex: 0, foundation: '4230759973', component: 'rtp', …}
logger.ts:60 PeerJS:  Server message received: {type: 'EXPIRE', src: 1673750880, dst: '1673299757'}
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible environment. It's really hard to tell what's the exact problem; the scope is too broad. It could be storage issue, environment setup issue, hardware issue(it is possible that one of your apps is eating up the port)...who knows.

Comment: @sungryeol Okay done, do tell me if this is sufficient enough.

Comment: @Joe you have a list of Google STUN servers in config, but I guess that option iceTransportPolicy: 'relay' selects only TURN servers, so maybe there is an issue with your TURN server.
Have you checked webrtc-internals tab in browser? There might be useful diagnostic info

Comment: I have the strongest feeling that it has something to do with the peers' IDs. I'm not sure what the issue is though.

Comment: @Joe It is not enough; it does not reproduce. It remains as a claim until we get the exact same error in a different device. A git repo with the exact same bug would be enough. If it only happens on windows, it must be reproducible on a windows docker image or virtualized window environment(parallels, UTM, vigrant, virtualbox...)

Comment: @sungryeol I will not do that. I have already met and exceeded the SO question specification. Plus, this code is runnable and reproducible without any "specific use-case" dependencies other than the scripts posted. This is how I know that you did not run the code posted.